# Using File constructor with directory name starting from root

Tags: java, io

Suppose I have a `.jar` file that exports a `temple.txt` into directory `~/output`. The code that does this is below. However suppose that this `output` folder is actually in `home/workspace/temp/output`. How do I use the `File(..)` constructor to send `temple.txt` to some completely different folder, such as `home/Desktop/hello/` ?

```
    public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String directory = "output";

            FileWriter fstream;
            BufferedWriter out;

            File file = new File(directory, "temple.txt");

            fstream = new FileWriter(file);
            out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

            out.write(String.valueOf(1));
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to send it to an absolute path, or something else?Can you be a little bit more specific on the question?

Comment: Change `directory`...You should also be using `System.getProperty("user.home")` to get the user's home directory ;)

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path? ie. File file = new File("home/workspace/temp2/output/temple.txt");

Comment: Yes. I can't set directory to the absolute path. It always works off `~./` no matter what I try. If I put `home//text.txt` or `home/text.txt` it will just say `No such file or directory` (since `/home/` doesn't exist in `home/workspace/temp/output`).

Comment: Absolute paths start with a forward slash /. Are you sure. You're doing this?

Comment: I am sure that `String directory = "//Home"` does not work.`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Home/temple.txt (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Unless you're running as root, you probably don't have permissions to write to /home. Try /tmp/

Comment: Also be consistent - paths are case sensitive - there is no /Home

Comment: Are you sure the directory exists? If not, you can create it with `File.mkdirs`

Comment: @Henry it's my home directory. Yes it exists